# ArrayList error :java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 26, size is 26

Tags: java, android

I have the following activity running different threads. I need to retrieve an array list but all I get is an exception. I found similar issues on google but I couldn't adapt the solution to my code.

Here is my class:

```
public class MapActivity  extends Activity {

    private int userIcon, jewelleryIcon;
    private GoogleMap theMap;
    private LocationManager locMan;
    private Marker userMarker;
    private Marker bijouterie;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    ArrayList<String> latList;
    ArrayList<String> longList;
    ArrayList<String> latitudeList;
    ArrayList<String> longitudeList;

    // URL to get JSON
    private static String url = "api";
    private static String url2 = "api";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Portrait only
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        // Check status of Google Play Services
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // Check Google Play Service Available
        try {
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
        }

        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        // Google Maps
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);




        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetJson().execute();


    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            JSONArray array = null;
            try {
                array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id --->" + id);
                 String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                 System.out.println("url --->" + url);
            //   shopurl.add(url);
                 String created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                 System.out.println("created_at --->" + created_at);
                 String updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
                 System.out.println("updated_at --->" + updated_at);
                 String name = jsonObject.getString("name");    
                 System.out.println("name --->" + name);
                // shopname.add(name);
                 JSONArray photos_urls = jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos_urls");
                 System.out.println("photos_urls --->" + photos_urls);
                 String address_string = jsonObject.getString("address_string");
                 System.out.println("address_string --->" + address_string);
            //   shopaddress.add(address_string);
                 JSONObject booklet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("booklet");
                 String id_booklet = booklet.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id_booklet --->" + id_booklet);
                 String url_booklet = booklet.getString("url");
                 System.out.println("url_booklet --->" + url_booklet);
                 String created_at_booklet = booklet.getString("created_at");
                 System.out.println("created_at_booklet --->" + created_at_booklet);
                 String updated_at_booklet = booklet.getString("updated_at");
                 System.out.println("updated_at_booklet --->" + updated_at_booklet);
                 String document_url = booklet.getString("document_url");
                 System.out.println("document_url --->" + document_url);
                 String presented = booklet.getString("presented");
                 System.out.println("presented --->" + presented);


                }
                    }
                 catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                 // 2e JSON

              // Creating service handler class instance
                 ServiceHandler sh2 = new ServiceHandler();

                 // Making a request to url and getting response
                 String jsonStr2 = sh2.makeServiceCall(url2, ServiceHandler.GET);

                 Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr2);

                 JSONArray array2 = null;
                try {
                    array2 = new JSONArray(jsonStr2);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    ArrayList<String> latitudeList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> longitudeList = new ArrayList<String>();


                    for (int j = 0; j <array2.length(); j++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = array2.getJSONObject(j);
                     JSONArray coordinates = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                    latitude = coordinates.getString(0);
                    Log.d("latitude: ", "> " + latitude);

                    latitudeList.add(latitude);

                    longitude = coordinates.getString(1);
                    Log.d("longitude: ", "> " + longitude);

                    latitudeList.add(latitude);
                    longitudeList.add(longitude);




                     JSONObject shop = jsonObject2.getJSONObject("shop");

                        String logo_thumbnail_url = shop.getString("logo_thumbnail_url");
                        System.out.println("logo_thumbnail_url --->" + logo_thumbnail_url);

                        }
                    latList = latitudeList;
                    longList = longitudeList;

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            return null;

    }

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){


            updatePlaces();
        }

    }

    private void updatePlaces(){

        userIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
        jewelleryIcon = R.drawable.pointeur;

        if(theMap==null){
            //map not instantiated yet
        }
        theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
        if(theMap != null){
            //ok - proceed
        }
        theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //update location
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
        double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        //if(userMarker==null) userMarker.remove();

        userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lastLatLng)
        .title("Vous êtes ici")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
        .snippet("Votre dernière position enregistrée"));

        theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 7.5f), 4000, null);

        String thelatitude;
        String thelongtitude;

        for (int i = 0; i < latList.size(); i++) {
            thelatitude  = latList.get(i);
            thelongtitude = longList.get(i);

            double latitudeFromString = Double.parseDouble(thelatitude);
            double longitudeFromString = Double.parseDouble(thelongtitude);

            LatLng SHOP = new LatLng(latitudeFromString, longitudeFromString);
            bijouterie = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(SHOP)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(jewelleryIcon)));


        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();//go back to the previous Activity
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backin, R.anim.backout);  
    }
}
```

And the log cat:

```
01-05 15:52:12.389: W/dalvikvm(15320): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d34300)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 26, size is 26
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.MapActivity.updatePlaces(MapActivity.java:272)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.MapActivity.access$6(MapActivity.java:237)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.MapActivity$GetJson.onPostExecute(MapActivity.java:232)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.MapActivity$GetJson.onPostExecute(MapActivity.java:1)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-05 15:52:12.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What line in your code is .MapActivity.updatePlaces(MapActivity.java:272) ?

Comment: thelongtitude = longList.get(i);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `doInBackground` method, you're adding **two** times the `latitude` in the latitude list, and just **one** time the `longitude` in the longitude list.

```
    latitudeList.add(latitude);
    longitude = coordinates.getString(1);
    Log.d("longitude: ", "> " + longitude);
    latitudeList.add(latitude); //<-- here why adding another time ?
```

And after you're doing :

```
latList = latitudeList;
longList = longitudeList;
```

I highly suspect that the `latList` is twice longer than the `longList`, and hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the line `thelongtitude = longList.get(i);` because you're looping from `0` to `latList.size()`(which is twice bigger `than longList.size()`).

Remove one `latitudeList.add(latitude);` and that should work.

Comment: Ooops my mistake. Thanks a lot, I need new glasses. I'll accept your answer in 5 min, I can't for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < latList.size(); i++) {
        thelatitude  = latList.get(i);
        thelongtitude = longList.get(i);
```

This code here is making the assumption that the longList is exactly the same length (or longer) as the latlist. If that assumption is not correct then it will fail here.